# Dictionary of lists and retrieving common values

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, search

I have a dictionary of lists and was wondering if there was a good way of obtaining all the common values. For instance:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

and within it I have say 4 keys, each one has a list and i would like to obtain all the values in the dictionary that have 'Oscar','Pablo','John' in it.

NOTE:  I do not know what i am looking for before hand, i just get this dictionary and need to find all the names that are in all three lists.

Return example:

Say I have a dictionary with

```
Key=1 Value = List with {'Oscar', 'John','Pablo','Pedro'}
Key=2 Value = List with {'Duvan','Samuel','Pablo','Pedro'}
Key=3 Value = List with {'Camilo','Pablo','Julian'}

Return a list of List with {'Pablo'}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try exploring LINQ. That has the answer you are looking for

Comment: yeah i was looking into that but not quite understand how that would work for a dictionary with lists in it

Comment: Do you need all three items to be in the list, or any of the three items to be in the list?

Comment: All three items must be on the lists

Comment: @jedgard Please, put a return example.

Comment: sure, let me put it on the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at it this way:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>()
{
    { 1, new List<string>() { "Oscar", "Pablo", "John" } },
    { 2, new List<string>() { "Foo", "Hello", "World" } },
};

var names = new HashSet<string>() { "John", "Oscar", "Pablo"};

var matchesAll = myDictionary.Values.Where(v => names.All(n => v.Contains(n)));

var matchesAny = myDictionary.Values.Where(v => names.Any(n => v.Contains(n)));
```

The two final choices are based on whether or not you want all of the words to match or any of the words.

---

As per your comment, if you want a list of names common in all of the dictionary values then you could do this:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>()
{
    { 1, new List<string>() { "Oscar", "Pablo", "John" } },
    { 2, new List<string>() { "Foo", "John", "World" } },
};

var commonInAll = myDictionary.Values.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y).ToList());
```

In this case you get just `{ "John" }` in the final `commonInAll` list.

Comment: What if i dont know what i am looking for, i just need all the ones that are on all three lists?

Comment: You need to do it the other way around. The way you're doing it, it will return all the list which contain the specified names only. Replace your condition with `.Where(v => names.All(n => v.Contains(n)))`.

Comment: @dotNET - Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @jedgard - Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah pretty much, what would be the difference between this one and @dasblinkenlight 's

Comment: @jedgard - dasblinkenlight's works fine, but it is good to learn to use `Aggregate` as it is very powerful.

Comment: @Enigmativity does this take care if there are 5 or 6 lists in the dictionary, just qurious

Comment: @jedgard - Yes, that's what `.Aggregate` does - takes an entire list and aggregates it down to a single value (or a list in this case).

Comment: and if there are three lists, and there is common on 2 but not in all 3, what would it result?, i would like it to be 0 (because its not in all) @Enigmativity

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah i just tested both approaches and I get results when 2 lists have in common but the other not :( . I was hoping to get 0 in that case - also problem is there could be like 6 lists in that dictionary

Comment: @jedgard - The `.Aggregate(...)` method returns 0 for me when there are three lists without a match in the third list. It doesn't matter how many lists there are.

Comment: yeah that worked, i was setting the wrong key. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Start by collecting all names from the list:

```
var allNames = dict.SelectMany(p => p.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now you can filter this list as follows:

```
var res = allNames
    .Where(s => dict.Count(p => p.Value.Contains(s)) == dict.Count)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: i am going to try it, i posted my scenario up top too

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 Dictionary<int, List<string>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
        myDictionary.Add(1, new List<string>()
            {
                "Oscar", "Pablo", "John"
            });
        myDictionary.Add(2, new List<string>()
            {
                "Foo", "Hello", "World"
            });

        var result = myDictionary.Where(c => c.Value.Contains("Oscar") && c.Value.Contains("Pablo") && c.Value.Contains("John")).ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
```

Comment: @dotNET I didn't downvote this, and I have no idea why one would downvote this, because it's a possible interpretation of the question.

Comment: I didnt either, so basically i could have dozens of those values, and they are all coming into that dictionary already, so i need to find all those that are in all lists of the dictionaru

Answer (score 0):

var namesToFilter = new List {
    "John",
    "Oscar",
    "Pablo"};

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>
{
    {1, new List<string> { "John", "Oscar", "Pablo"}},
    {2, new List<string> { "Oscar", "Olivia"}},
    {3, new List<string> { "Pablo", "Paula"}},
    {4, new List<string> { "Steve", "Stella"}},
};
var matchedKeys= myDictionary
.Where(d => namesToFilter.Where(str => d.Value.Any(v => v == str)).Count() == namesToFilter.Count())
.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

Console.Write(matchedKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        myDictionary.Add(1, new List<string>() { "Oscar", "Pablo" });
        myDictionary.Add(2, new List<string>() { "John", "OtherName" });

        //Returns item from myDictionary that contains Oscar. Modify where linq query to your necessity
        Dictionary<int, List<string>> myNewDic = myDictionary.Where(dicItem => dicItem.Value.Contains("Oscar")).ToDictionary(dicItem => dicItem.Key, dicItem => dicItem.Value);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate *why* and *how* this solves the OPs issue?